# make menu header turn red one at a time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Was recently trying to play around JavaScript until I got stuck here...

I made four menu headers, each of which when clicked turns red, to show that the menu header is "active". The problem however is, *I want just one to turn red at a time*, instead of all menu headers turning red for every header clicked.

```js
let menuHeader = document.querySelectorAll('div.menu_header');

menuHeader.forEach((head) => {
  head.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!head.classList.contains('active_red')) {
      head.classList.add('active_red');
    } else {
      head.classList.remove('active_red');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Ebrima';
  background-color: #444444;
}

nav#nav_menu_query_off {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #222222;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;
}

nav#nav_menu_query_off menu#main_menu li.main_list_item div.menu_header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav#nav_menu_query_off menu li {
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

nav#nav_menu_query_off menu#main_menu li.main_list_item:not(:first-child) {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.active_red {
  color: red;
}

nav::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav_menu_query_off">
  <menu id="main_menu">
    <li class="main_list_item">
      <div class="menu_header">menu one</div>
      <div class="menu_body">
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="main_list_item">
      <div class="menu_header">menu two</div>
      <div class="menu_body">
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="main_list_item">
      <div class="menu_header">menu three</div>
      <div class="menu_body">
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="main_list_item">
      <div class="menu_header">menu four</div>
      <div class="menu_body">
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
      </div>
    </li>
  </menu>
</nav>
```

Please help me out anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cycle through the other menuHeaders and remove all the `active_red` classes first, and then apply the class to the current element.

```js
const menuHeaders = document.querySelectorAll('.menu_header');

function removeClass(els) {
  els.forEach(mh => mh.classList.remove('active_red'));
}

menuHeaders.forEach(head => {
  head.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (head.classList.contains('active_red')) {
      removeClass(menuHeaders);
    } else {
      removeClass(menuHeaders); 
      head.classList.add('active_red');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Ebrima';
  background-color: #444444;
}

nav#nav_menu_query_off {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #222222;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;
}

nav#nav_menu_query_off menu#main_menu li.main_list_item div.menu_header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav#nav_menu_query_off menu li {
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

nav#nav_menu_query_off menu#main_menu li.main_list_item:not(:first-child) {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.active_red {
  color: red;
}

nav::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav_menu_query_off">
  <menu id="main_menu">
    <li class="main_list_item">
      <div class="menu_header">menu one</div>
      <div class="menu_body">
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="main_list_item">
      <div class="menu_header">menu two</div>
      <div class="menu_body">
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="main_list_item">
      <div class="menu_header">menu three</div>
      <div class="menu_body">
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="main_list_item">
      <div class="menu_header">menu four</div>
      <div class="menu_body">
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
        <menu class="sub_menu"></menu>
      </div>
    </li>
  </menu>
</nav>
```

Comment: Aw snap, it works just fine. The only thing is that the active header stays red even if I click it again. Please help me fix it so it turns back to white after clicking the active header again. Pleeeeeeaaaase. Thank you.

Comment: @Matrion does that make sense from a UX perspective? Surely at least one menu must be active at any given time?

Comment: Please @Andy help me out anyway please?

Comment: You really made my day sir, I actually thought you forgot me. Really don't know how to thank you enough. Forgive me for my impatience. Thank you sir.

Comment: It was 14 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
let menuHeader = document.querySelectorAll('div.menu_header');

menuHeader.forEach((head) => {
  head.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('active_red');

    if (head === elements[0]) {
      head.classList.remove('active_red');
    } else {
      if (elements[0]) elements[0].classList.remove('active_red');
      head.classList.add('active_red');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Aw man, it does not work.

Comment: Can anyone help me out, please? Andy is so close.

Comment: Can anybody help me with a bit more precise answer, please? Mr. Andy came so close to nailing it.

Comment: No, it is still not working. I feel like giving up now.